# How to pass results from methods in PHP as variables / array into Twig and display in the html?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, twig

I've got a repo on github for this project: https://github.com/villimagg/php-mvc-twig

I'm having huge difficulties finding out how you pass results from a method in an MVC pattern to be displayed in the html using Twig template engine.

This project I got on github is just my simple bare-bones mvc framework which I'm using to learn how things work and I want to include the Twig template engine. So far I have no problems using just php and passing results into the view, and so far I've managed to have Twig display the template with the css and all. But when I need to retrieve some dynamic data from methods f.ex. and display it using Twig, I can't figure out how that is done.

Is there anyone who wants to help me? I guess more newbies like me wonder about similar things as well.
Please download the project on github, or fork it, and share your thoughts with us.

I want to express my gratitude to the opensource community for everything I've learned so far, which is basically everything I know in programming. Thank you a thousand times.

Kind regards, Villi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply pass the variables in an array, as the second `render`'s parameter.

```
$this->view->render('error/error', array(
  'string' => $string,
  'array'  => $array
));
```

And display it:

```
{{ string }}

{% for element in array %}
  element
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks Sammy. There were some fantastic suggestions you did on the github repo. I will definitely take these suggestions under consideration and apply them. Turns out there's a whole lot to learn yet ;) Thanks again. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually learning about the MVC framework currently and I just started using Twig so I was looking for a tutorial or article on how to incorporate both of them. Turns out, if you Google "PHP MVC Twig" you come up as the first result on Github and StackOverflow

This tutorial will probably help you out or at least push you in the right direction.

http://php-html.net/tutorials/model-view-controller-in-php/

Comment: Nice. Thank you. Haven't seen this tutorial before. Will definitely look into it. Thanks again.